# Configure SSLOpenSSLConfCmd to support B-283

Tags: apache-2.4

We need to setup TLS Client authentication with the following information:
client certificate: It is an EC sect283r1 (NIST B-283) certificate.
server: Apache 2.4 in Debian 11.

The error we got from Apache log is:
SSL Library Error: error:1414D17A:SSL routines:tls12_check_peer_sigalg:wrong curve

Can you please help.... Thanks

Comment: perhaps check which curves are compatible with your system "openssl ecparam -list_curves"